# Finding a loop invariant to prove a simple summing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, loops, data-structures, proof, invariants

I am currently learning Loop Invariants and is wondering whether I have generated them correctly here. The algorithm pseudocode is:

```
**EvenSumming(A)**
outcome=0
for i=1 to n
 if A[i] is even
  outcome=outcome+A[i]
return outcome
```

So far my LI and proving:

Loop Invariant (LI): At every iteration, the variable outcome is always even and at most can only be composed of i-1 elements originally in A[i....n].

Initialization: Let i = 1, thus outcome starts at 0, which makes it an even number and is composed of 0 elements from A[1...n]

Maintenance:  By math, we have that adding two even numbers always results in an even number, and since every iteration in the array increments i  by 1 then trivially we know that there are i-1 elements that have been iterated through before i. Thus, at iteration i, outcome will be an even value composed of at most i-1 elements from A[i...n]

Termination: At termination, let i > n and thus we can say that i = n+1. Then by LI we have that outcome is still even value composed from at most n elements originally existing in A[n]

Comment: "At termination, let i > n and thus we can say that i = n+1."  i>n does not imply i=n+1.

Comment: @ScottHunter does this mean i have to say that i is at least n+1 so. i >= n+1 ?

Comment: Why can't you just say i=n+1 because that's how for loops work?

Comment: You have proven that `outcome` was even, but you have not proven that `outcome` ended up being exactly the sum of `A`'s even elements. Also, your initiation step should correspond to before i=1, not to the iteration where i=1.